# When I read a file into an array and print it, why is there an extra whitespace at the beginning of each line after the first?

Tags: perl

I am reading a file into an array and printing the contents like this:

```
open (FILE, "ans.txt");
@file = <FILE>;
print "@file\n";
```

The file looks like this:

```
51.5440622646247 - 31.2571428571429
51.5440622646247 - 48.0616834439923
```

But the output has an extra space at the beginning of every line after the first:

```
51.5440622646247 - 31.2571428571429
 51.5440622646247 - 48.0616834439923
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: This happens, because when you print interpolated `@array` e.g. inside the double quotes `"@arr"`, the perl put an separator character between elements of array. The default value is space. And it is appear on the second line, because the elements of the array `@file` contains the `\n` character too.

Answer (score 4):

Pass your file lines to `print` as a list, instead of interpolating in the string:

```
print @file, "\n";
```

Your problem arises because when you interpolate an array `"@file\n"`, it is equivalent to the following:

```
print join($", @file) . "\n";
```

Search for `$LIST_SEPARATOR` in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more info.

Comment: And what is the answer

Comment: @AymanSalah That comment was a reply to another person's comment that has since been deleted.  Deleted my reply as well.